# Pass function with different signature than is expected

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, amqp

I am using [AMQP library for Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/amqp) in a message consuming console application. I am binding a message handler like this:

```
  consumeMsgs ch "tasks" Ack taskHandler
```

My problem is that `consumeMsgs` expects a message handler with this signature:

```
taskHandler :: (Message, Envelope) -> IO ()
```

...but I need to pass in additional `Channel` and a `Lock` (*`Channel` so I can publish the result to a different queue, `Lock` for printing to console*), like this:

```
taskHandler :: (Message, Envelope) -> Channel -> MVar () -> IO ()
```

I come from Javascript land, but I don't expect a dirty solution like a global variable. What can be done here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little unclear on your constraints, but if you have what you need available at the `consumeMsgs` call site, you can use a closure.  (I assume `ch` is the channel you want)

```
lock <- ...
consumeMsgs ch "tasks" Ack (\(msg,env) -> taskHandler (msg,env) ch lock)
```

(It's not strictly necessary to match on the tuple `(msg,env)` since it's just used directly, it was just the best name for the thing I could think of)

If you change the order of the arguments to `taskHandler` you can get a very idiomatic Haskell solution with partial application:

```
taskHandler :: Channel -> MVar () -> (Message, Envelope) -> IO ()

...

consumeMsgs ch "tasks" Ack (taskHandler ch lock)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is beautiful 

Answer (score 2):

This is where partial application comes in.

If you change the order of the arguments to

```
taskHandler :: Channel -> MVar () -> (Message, Envelope) -> IO ()
```

Then you can partially apply `taskHandler` to just a `Channel` and an `MVar ()`, i.e. `taskHandler channel mvar`. This will return a new function which is precisely the type that `consumeMsgs` expects.